# JQTouch returning to same position after watching video

Tags: iphone, jqtouch

I've been playing with JQTouch for a while, not withstanding the lack 
of documentation I've managed to get something working for my site

http://iphone.bmxmdb.com

but I have a problem, after  watching a video on an iPhone, the app 
returns to the front screen and loses where the user was navigated to. 
Is there anyway of storing the users previous position in the "app" so 
I can return them to that place. 
I've been googling for days, bought the peepcode video, and still have 
little idea. 
Is it even possible?

thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My educated guess is that the .data method is what you need - see http://api.jquery.com/data/